# React-joyride - How can I customize the Joyride to appear where I want to?

Tags: reactjs, web

How can I change where the pop-up of the Joyride appears? I have this column in my website, and at this moment the text its appearing above, but I want to change it to appear in the left and centralized. What can I do?

[image]

My code:

```js
return (<Joyride
        wrapperOptions={{
            class : "teste"
        }}
        steps={[]}
        run={true}
        continuous={true}
        scrollToFirstStep={true}
        showSkipButton
        showProgress={true}    
        locale={
            {
                back: t('lblTutorialBack'),
                close:t('lblTutorialClose'),
                last: t('lblTutorialLast'),
                next: t('lblTutorialNext'),
                skip: t('lblTutorialSkip'),
            }
        }
        styles={{
            buttonNext: {
                background: '#812990'
            },
            options: {
                primaryColor: '#812990',
            }
        }}
        {
        ...props
        }
    />)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `placement` option of the `floaterProps`.  Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-cdn-404w9?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactJoyride from "react-joyride";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const steps = [
    {
      target: "#step1",
      content: "This is my awesome feature!"
    },
    {
      target: "#step2",
      content: "This another awesome feature!"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ReactJoyride floaterProps={{ placement: "left" }} steps={steps}>
        Test
      </ReactJoyride>
      <button id="step1">Step 1</button>
      <button id="step2">Step 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to set the `placement` on a per `step` basis, that is also possible:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactJoyride from "react-joyride";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const steps = [
    {
      target: "#step1",
      content: "This is my awesome feature!",
      placement: "right"
    },
    {
      target: "#step2",
      content: "This another awesome feature!",
      placement: "left"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ReactJoyride continuous={true} steps={steps}>
        Test
      </ReactJoyride>
      <button id="step1">Step 1</button>
      <button id="step2">Step 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great :D